# Regexp replace country code and blank spaces from phone number

Tags: postgresql

Please help me with this issue. I'm very bad at regex things. I need to remove country code and blank spaces at once from phone number. Something like:
'+12 345 678' to '345678'. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is this always this structure? +, two digits, space, ...

Comment: not always. it can be '+12345678" then it'd be '345678', country code if exists will be always the same digits e.g '+12'

Answer (score 0):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c5cb791337bf07cc4af97124d489e9cc)

Assuming the country code always is the first three characters:

```
SELECT replace(right('+12 345 678', -3), ' ', '')
```

`right('xyz', -3)` removes the first three characters

`replace('xyz', ' ', '')` removes the spaces.

More general:

```
SELECT 
    replace(right(numbers, -3), ' ', '')
FROM
    phone
```

Comment: @Tymon Did this help? If not, what needs to changed? If so, please don't forget to upvote (honors the repliers work) and accept (shows other users that the question has been answered) :)